# Program that removes duplicated elements and return its new elements and size

Tags: java, arrays

My code is almost done but the problem is the returning size it supposed to return the size after the duplicated elements has been removed. it wont output the right size.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    int size;
    int i;
    int j;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Enter the number of elements: ");
    size = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\n");
    int myArray[] = new int [size];
    
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter value for num["+i+"]: ");
        myArray[i] = scn.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.print("\nThe inputted values are ");
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" " + myArray[i] + ",");
    }
    
    System.out.print("\nDuplicate values ");
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length-1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i+1; j < myArray.length; j++)
        {
            if ((myArray[i] == myArray[j]) && (i != j))
            {
                System.out.print(" " +myArray[j]+ ",");
            }
        }
    }
    int length = myArray.length;
    length = remove_dupli(myArray,length);
    
    System.out.print("\nThe new values of the array are ");
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" " +myArray[i]+", ");
    }  
    System.out.println("\nThe new length of the array is: "+array_sort(myArray));
}
```

is there a problem on this part?

```
public static int remove_dupli(int myArray[], int n){  
    if (n==0 || n==1){  
        return n;  
    }  
    int[] temp = new int[n];  
    int j = 0;  
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++){  
        if (myArray[i] != myArray[i+1]){  
            temp[j++] = myArray[i];  
        }  
     }  
    temp[j++] = myArray[n-1];  
    
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++){  
        myArray[i] = temp[i];  
    }  
    return j;  
}
```

or this part?

```
public static int array_sort(int[] myArray) {
     int index = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] != myArray[index-1])
            myArray[index++] = myArray[i];
    }
  return index;
 }
}
```

The output should be:

Enter Number of Elements: 4

Enter value for num[0]: 2

Enter value for num[1]: 2

Enter value for num[2]: 3

Enter value for num[3]: 4

The inputted values are 2,2,3,4

Duplicated values 2,

The new values of the array are 2,3,4

The new length of the array is 3

Comment: How is the expected output different from your current output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you are using to find the duplicate elements is fine but you are not actually changing the elements in the array , you are just printing the non-duplicate ones, best approach is to change the value of the duplicate elements as a flag and then to find the length of the array after the duplicates have been removed,it will be easy :

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++)
       {
           if((array[i]==array[j]) && i!=j)
               System.out.println("duplicate value:"array[j]);
               array[j]=-1;
       }
}
```

So, now for the array length after removing the duplicate elements is:

```
int count=0;
 for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   if(array[i]!=-1)
    count ++;
 }
```

Comment: it surely counts the correct length after it removes the duplicate, but it prints a -1 and other numbers... can you elaborate on where should I put your codes maybe i just misplaced your code.

Comment: I made a small mistake and have edited my answer check if it helps you .

Comment: oh yes it helps me a lot but the remaining problem is it keeps printing "-1" on the new values of the array